# Programmatically uncheck checkboxcolumn in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

How can I programmatically uncheck all rows in a DataGridViewCheckboxColumn in a datagridview?

I can get the correct value of the checkbox using

```
(bool)row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index].FormattedValue
```

but that's only a getter.

I have tried setting the value of the cell using

```
(bool)row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index].value = false
```

but that doesn't affect the FormattedValue.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do sth. like:

```
(row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).value = false;
```

You just *forgot* to cast to the correct type, a generic `DataGridViewCell` doesn't know its value-type.

Comment: This kind of works. Your code don't affect FormattedValue, which I use to get the value of the checkbox. We can turn the problem around and blame FormattedValue. You see, when I try to get the boolean value from (row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).value, the app crashes. This has made it necessary for me to stick with FormattedValue.

Comment: I actually used this to set the value to true but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried casting the first control in the checkbox column to checkbox and then setting 'Checked' to true?

Try something to this extent.

```
((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)e.Rows[0].Cells[0]).Selected = true
```

Comment: Perhaps a code snippet? And what do you mean by "the first control"? Row, cell...?

Comment: A datagridviewrow have no .Controls[].

Answer (score 1):

you should just use `YourDataGridview.EndEdit()` after checking.

```
(row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).value = false;
YourDataGridview.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked but you can try;

```
CheckBox cb = (row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index].Controls[0] as CheckBox);
if(cb != null)
{
    cb.Checked = false;
}
```

It's type may be different. Just debug and cast it to what it is.

Comment: A datagridviewcell have no .Controls[]

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  dr.Cells[0].Value = true;//sıfırın
}
```

Comment: Please always translate your code (or at least the comments) into English when you post something here

Answer (score 0):

If you use dataGridView1_ContextClick just for do "false" datagidviewCheckBox Column need this Code :

```
dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
```

but if you need all rows of CheckBoxColumns of DataGrid :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        r.Cells["statusBox"].Value = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you wish to do

If it is about **the selected row**, then you can:

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewName.CurrentRow;

//This will assign the opposite value of the Cell Content
row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value = !Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value);
```

However if you wish to do it **for the whole DataGridView table** then:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewName.Rows)

   {
        //This will assign the opposite value of the Cell Content
        row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value = !Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value);
   }
```

Whatever suites you. Keep it up!

Answer (score -1):

Loop through each row of grid view and use the find control method:

```
foreach ( GridViewRow row in myGridView )
{
     CheckBox checkBox = ( CheckBox ) row.FindControl( "myCheckBox" );
     checkbox.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps FindControl is just something for the web? I'm developing a WinForms app.

Answer (score -1):

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridviewname.Rows)

  {
    row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1_Name].Value = false;
  }
```