# How to Check and Uncheck a checkbox in datagridview c#.net

Tags: c#

Can any one tell me how to check a check box in a datagrid view?

I have a datagridview in my UI but the check box column is not working. (I'm not able to check the checkbox)

Any kind reply will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What's the `EditMode` property of your grid view? Make sure your rows aren't read only either.

Comment: [Programmatically uncheck checkboxcolumn in datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725384/programmatically-uncheck-checkboxcolumn-in-datagridview)

Comment: What data you bind to datagridview?